# Wait in other thread for answer from Messagebox

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, messagebox

I have a working **class** (Synchronization.java in my case) with **static methods** that uploads/downloads some data from and to the server. In some cases, I want to open a (**JavaFX**) MessageDialog (MessageBox) and ask the user if he wants to do a certain activity or not (answers: yes/no). To open this MessageDialog I need the controller from the main window and the stage. Moreover, as I am on another thread I can open the MessageBox in the UI-thread with `Platform#runlater`. The Synchronization.java should **wait until I get the user's response from the MessageDialog** (which is in the other thread) - i.e. after I get the response from the user, the corresponding method should be called.

**Edit:**  I found a solution which I added as an answer. However, I am not fully convinced that this is the best solution for my problem. If anyone has a suggestion, thanks for sharing!

Comment: how did you try to solve the problem? where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried both suggestions I described above. Both look very improper to me and didn't really work... I updated the thread above to describe what I am currently trying. thanks.

Comment: it would be easier to help you if you provided some code to show up your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with the code below. This works, but I have the feeling, that there are better ways...

```
public static boolean showMessageCheckToUpload() {
   @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
   final FutureTask query = new FutureTask(new Callable() {
      @Override
      public Object call() throws Exception {
         boolean uploadDisk = MessageBoxTwoChoicesController.showDialogBox(
                    stage, "Upload disk",
                    "Do you want to upload the current Disk to the server?", "Yes", "No");
         return uploadDisk;
      }
    });
    Platform.runLater(query);
    try {
       return (boolean) query.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
       return false;
    }
}
```